# why my arrow function inside a object doesn't works?

Tags: javascript, object, arrow-functions

please, I have a doub
Why with arrow function inside in a object doesn't work?
How we do to can make it works with arrow function?

```js
let person = {
  name: "Homer Simpson",
  birdYear: 2000,
  getAge: function() { // WORKS!
    return 2020 - this.birdYear
  },
  getAgeWithArrowF: () => { // Doesn't works
    return 2020 - this.birdYear // using person.birdYear wrks but i need with (this.birdYear)
    // cant reach birdYear =(
  }
};

// The call

console.log(person.getAge()); // 2020
console.log(person.getAgeWithArrowF()); // NaN
```

THANKS!

Comment: "How we do to can make it works with arrow function?" — You can't. Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: The fat arrow transfers the context the object belongs to inside the function. On the other hand, `function()` transfers the object's own context inside the function.

Comment: *this* in a function expression (first example) is set by the call. If it's called as `person.getAge()`, *this* will be *person*. But *this* in an arrow function (second example) is inherited from the enclosing execution context. Since it's global code, it will be the global object.

Comment: @JeremyThille—arrow functions have their own execution context (otherwise variables would be inherited too), only their *this* is from the enclosing context.